# How to Convert Vector to String in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm hoping to find a simple way of converting a vector of numbers to a string in matlab.

Lets say I have a vector b,

b[1 2 4 3];

is there something simple such as

b = vect2str(b);

Comment: Or do you mean `1   2   4   3`? Or `[1 2 4 3]`?

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
 b = [1 2 4 3];
 b = num2str(b);
```

Comment: Perfect, it can also be combined with strcat to concatenate and expand a vector: `strcat(',', num2str([1:3]'))`